# Google Anylytics SDK in Swift using GAIDictionaryBuilder raise error

Tags: swift, ios8, google-analytics-api

The error message is

```
xxx.swift:171:45: Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSMutableDictionary!' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

The code is

```
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("Category", action: "action", label: nil, value: nil).build())
```

Google analytics SDK version is

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '3.0.9'
```

Comment: did you add #import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
to the bridging header?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @YamiFraiman 

pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIFields.h>